# Property syntax, Am I accessing the ivar directly or going through the getter/setter?

Tags: objective-c

I am new to objective-c and am a little confused as to what I am accessing by when calling a property various ways in code.

```
// MyClass.h
@interface MyClass : NSObject {
}
@property ( nonatomic, retain ) NSString *name;

@end

//MyClass.m
#import "MyClass.h"

@implementation MyClass
@synthesize name;
// other code...
@end
```

I am unclear whether I am accessing the backing ivar or going through the getter and setter in using the following syntax (I will include my assumptions as to what I think it's doing):

- `name = @"Geoff";` is this going through the property setter or setting the ivar directly?
- `self.name = @"Geoff";` going through the setter
- `self->name = @"Geoff;"` direct ivar access
- `[ name release ];` is this accessing the ivar directly or going through the getter?

I know this can be disambiguated by setting the ivar in the synthesize statement like: `@synthesize name=_name` as is done in a lot of the XCode 4 IOS templates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `name = @"Geoff";` is setting the ivar directly.
- `[ name release ];` is accessing the ivar directly.

If you don't see `self.` and you aren't calling a method to get or set the variable, then you are accessing the ivar.

For more details, see [The Objective-C Programming Language](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocProperties.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH17).